# Table imported into Matlab from CSV, variable name prefixed by "x___"

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a bunch of automatically-generated CSV files with headers, which I'd like to import into Matlab 2016a as a table. I used code such as

```
T = readtable('d:\test.csv', 'readvariablenames', true);
```

However, even though the name of the CSV's first column is "runNr", the first column in the Matlab table gets named "x___runNr"

[image]
[image]

This clearly has something to do with the CSV files being in a slightly format different from that expected by Matlab. For instance, it could be that my CSVs have a Byte Order Mark in the beginning. Still, I am not sure what to do to fix this, since I cannot change the format of the CSVs. Readtable, on the other hand, gives me the output format I am most comfortable with.

Upon calling readtable, the following warning is issued:

```
"Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. "
```

However, some of my CSVs (perhaps produced by a different version of the software that outputs them) are still read OK, and for those CSVs the same warning is displayed, thus the warning alone is not indicative of the problem.

Comment: could you upload one of the files with the prefix?

Comment: The prefix is only visible in the output of readtable. I've uploaded the test.csv file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9b7e88630a575aaac7d75083aaaae38c20191022125303/56e797).

Comment: unfortunately i can't recrate the 'x__' part. However, the warning comes every time, because the name must not have a dot (.) in it like 'fMRI_Patel_task.thisRepN'. that is changed to an underscore

Comment: What Matlab version do you use? A user on the Matlab forum imported this with no problem in 2019b, so this could just be a limitation of older versions like mine. Also, I don't think the dot is the problem, since the CSVs that import normally even in 2016a (i.e., without the x__ prefix) also have variable names containing dots.

Comment: mine is 2019a, so unfortunately it might be. To clarify: the warning is caused by a dot in a name, thats why it is no indication for your issue

Comment: Got it. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Consider adding a function/script to read the .csv as a text file, and create a modified copy of it, by reading line-by-line of the original and copying with modifications, that would exclude a Byte Order Mark, non acceptable variable names. This approach should provide you the needed control/conditions without disrupting the workflow too much.

Comment: Thanks @Mefitico, that's an option indeed

Comment: Is the data read correctly? Would a solution that first uses `readtable`, and then fix the variable names in the table be sufficient? For example just by stripping everything up to the `_`. Or are the prefixes different for each file?

Comment: The prefix seems to be the same up until now, so just correcting for it manually is reasonable, assuming I don't find a solution that just imports them correctly to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the source of the problem:
Like you have suspected, the encoding of your CSV file is "[UTF-8-BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)" (I saw it using Notepad++).

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF

MATLAB R2019a knows to ignore the first 3 bytes, but R2016a is "confused" by the 3 characters, and add `x___` prefix to `runNr`.

A workaround, is create a temporary file with out the first 3 characters:

```
f = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
A = fread(f, '*uint8');
fclose(f);

if all(A(1:3) == hex2dec(['EF'; 'BB'; 'BF']))
    f = fopen('tmp.csv', 'w');
    fwrite(f, A(4:end)); %Skip first 3 characters.
    fclose(f);
    T = readtable('tmp.csv', 'readvariablenames', true);
else
    T = readtable('test.csv', 'readvariablenames', true);
end
```

There might be more efficient solutions (like simply removing the `x___`).